# Transaction error in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a project
https://github.com/ivartanian/onlinecontrol
 in Spring MVC + JPA, initially worked with the Spring configuration through XML. Now I am trying to set up the project through JAVA Config (without XML). The project starts, but when I create a new user(entity User), an error transaction. But if I create another Entity this error not occur. If this XML configuration error does not occur too.

Please tell me what the cause of the error. 
I would be glad of any help

My XML config is:

```
    <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.service"/>

    <!-- enables scanning for @Transactional annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- ========================= DATASOURCE DEFINITION ========================= -->

    <!-- Configurer that replaces ${...} placeholders with values from a properties file -->
    <!-- (in this case, JDBC-related settings for the dataSource definition below) -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:spring/data-access.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>

    <!-- Database initializer. If any of the script fails, the initialization stops. -->
    <!-- As an alternative, for embedded databases see <jdbc:embedded-database/>. -->
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="${jdbc.initLocation}"/>
        <jdbc:script location="${jdbc.dataLocation}"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

    <!-- DataSource configuration for the Jetty jdbc connection -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDataSource">
        <property name="url">
            <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.dao.jpa"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.security"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.configuration"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                  p:database="${jpa.database}" p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}"/>
            <!-- the 'database' parameter refers to the database dialect being used.
                By default, Hibernate will use a 'HSQL' dialect because 'jpa.database' has been set to 'HSQL'
                inside file spring/data-access.properties

             -->
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <!-- Voters -->
    <bean id="accessDecisionManager"
          class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
        <constructor-arg name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!--<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">-->
        <!--<property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="customPermissionEvaluator"/>-->
    <!--</bean>-->
    <!--<bean id="customPermissionEvaluator"  class="com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.security.impl.CustomPermissionEvaluator"/>-->

    <!-- SECURITY -->
    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Validators -->
    <bean id="userValidator" class="com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.validators.UserValidator"/>

    <!-- Messages -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="ru"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Converters -->
    <bean id="conversionService"
          class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
        <property name="converters">
            <set>
                <bean class="com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.converters.StringToClazz"/>
                <bean class="com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.converters.StringToUser"/>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My Java config is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({
        "com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.aspects",
        "com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.configuration",
        "com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.controller",
        "com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.dao",
        "com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.model",
        "com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.validators",
        "com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.security",
        "com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.service"})
@PropertySource("classpath:spring/data-access.properties")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    private ClazzService clazzService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor sourceAdvisor;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        JDBCDataSource dataSource = new JDBCDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() {
        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource());

        CompositeDatabasePopulator compositeDatabasePopulator = new CompositeDatabasePopulator();

        compositeDatabasePopulator.addPopulators(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new DefaultResourceLoader().getResource(environment.getProperty("jdbc.initLocation"))));
        compositeDatabasePopulator.addPopulators(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new DefaultResourceLoader().getResource(environment.getProperty("jdbc.dataLocation"))));
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(compositeDatabasePopulator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.model"});

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");

        em.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return txManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/WEB-INF/jsp/**").addResourceLocations("/jsp/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true)
                .useJaf(false)
                .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
                .mediaType("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .defaultContentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

        registry.viewResolver(resolver);

        registry.beanName();
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new StringToClazz(clazzService));
        registry.addConverter(new StringToUser(userService));
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource configureMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("ru"));
        return localeResolver;
    }

}
```

The error occurs when you call this.em.persist(user) in the method save(User user):

```
@Repository
public class JpaUserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public JpaUserDaoImpl() {
    }

    public JpaUserDaoImpl(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    public User findByEmail(String email) throws DataAccessException {
        Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT user FROM User user WHERE user.email =:email");
        query.setParameter("email", email);

        List resultList = query.getResultList();
        if (resultList.isEmpty()) {
            return null; // handle no-results case
        } else {
            return (User)resultList.get(0);
        }

//        return (User) query.getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(Long id) {
        Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT user FROM User user WHERE user.id =:id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);

        List resultList = query.getResultList();
        if (resultList.isEmpty()) {
            return null; // handle no-results case
        } else {
            return (User)resultList.get(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() throws DataAccessException {
        Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT user FROM User user");
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {

        if (user == null){
            return;
        }

        if (user.getId() == null) {
            this.em.persist(user);
        }
        else {
            this.em.merge(user);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(User user) throws DataAccessException {
        if (user == null){
            return;
        }
        this.em.remove(user);
    }

}
```

That error:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:275)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.dao.jpa.JpaUserDaoImpl.save(JpaUserDaoImpl.java:68)
    at com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.saveUser(UserServiceImpl.java:51)
    at com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.controller.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:112)
    at com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.controller.UserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2ef7ce5a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterAdvice.java:43)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.controller.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9f848f41.createUser(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:806)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceRun.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceRun.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceRun.run(ExecuteProduceRun.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:559)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do you have other deployment errors?

Comment: could update the question with transaction managers you are using?The ones with @Transactional annotation..

Comment: Go through this link, Hope this will help for your requirement.. http://levelup.lishman.com/spring/hibernate-orm/quick-start.php

Comment: @Jens Do you have other deployment errors? No, the problem only when creating / deleting a user. The problem occurs when entitiManager.persist (user)
The transaction manager is trying to get entitimanager in ThreadLocal and return null.

Comment: I can not see `entitiManager.persist(user)` in your code?

Comment: @Jens I am edit my question and add em.

Comment: What about COmponent scan dirs? Looks like they are different in XML and Config class. Is it possible than some key classes are not scanned and transaction is not started from @Transactional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stacktrace, there are no Spring AOP class listed between these two lines:

```
   at com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.saveUser(UserServiceImpl.java:51)
    at com.vizaco.onlinecontrol.controller.UserController.createUser(UserController.java:112)
```

Your Dependency Injection is not setup right..  the Controller should be getting a Spring Bean of UserService